# 12v to 3.3 v logic level shifter?

Tags: circuit-design, level-shifting, hardware

For my application I have to read 12V pulses from a optical encoder into a GPIO pin of a Raspberry Pi. What could be the best solution to convert 12v HTL signals to 3.3V for RPi GPIO input? Is a level shifter, resistor+clamping diode or an opto isolator good for this application?

Comment: How fast are the pulses coming in (frequency)?  This will help determine whether you can use opto-isolators or not.

Comment: First check the datasheet to see if the encoder can be run off a compatible voltage. "12V TTL" doesn't make sense : TTL is generally 5V.

Comment: I saw the datasheet.its 12 HTL

Comment: The pulse frequency is 1 pulse every 2ms.

Comment: @kunalp Ok good, this is well within the range of most opto-isolators.  Easy solution.

Comment: HTL logic is usually used in very high noise environments. Are you sure that by converting it to low voltage and connecting to Arduino you won't create something that is useless in such environment?

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fehvXi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would bet that a couple resistors and a clamping diode are ok if the environment is not too hostile (big motors, long cables, high currents...).

You can also add a small capacitor in parallel with the diode, it aids in reducing spikes if any. The resistor R1 could (or probably should) be slightly bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Look at CD74hc4050. It is designed for level shifting.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4049.pdf

"They have a modified input
protection structure that enables these parts to be usedas
logic level translators which convert high-level logic to a lowlevel logic while operating off the low-level logic supply. For
example, 15-V input pulse levels can be down-converted to
0-V to 5-V logic levels. The modified input protection
structure protects the input from negative electrostatic
discharge. "

Available as DIPs also.
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/CD74HC4050E/296-9213-5-ND/376792

Better response times (faster) than the old CMOS stuff.